# disabling fields in formlets/digestive-functors?

Tags: haskell, webforms, applicative, digestive-functors

With formlets/digestive-functors, I'm trying to figure out how selectively disable fields at run-time. Disabling a field would disable both the showing of the field as well as validation.

Contrived example: Suppose our basic form data type looks like:

```
data Info =
  Info {
     favcolor :: String,
     deptId   :: Int,
     company  :: String,
     agree    :: Boolean
  }
```

but the `deptId` field should only be shown if the user is an employee, otherwise the `company` field should be shown. And the `agree` field should be shown if the user hasn't already clicked the "Agree" box.

I don't want to create a different form type for each possible variation: (favcolor, deptId, agree), (favcolor, deptId), (favcolor, company, agree), (favcolor, company). What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I think this breaks the digestive functors model and can't be done. It would make a good feature request, though!